# How to filter JSONB field by substring (SQLAlchemy, Postgresql)

Tags: python, json, postgresql, filter, sqlalchemy

I would like to filter JSONB field containing substring using SQLAlchemy.

I know that I can use contains() to find exactly the same key but I want to find substring of that key. Like using ilike() with Text fields. I would like to do that for both columns, recipient and params. But if I will get help for one I will find out how do do that with second column.

```
class NotificationMixin:

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    recipient = Column(JSONB, nullable=False)
    params = Column(JSONB, default={})

class EmailResource(AdminDataTableResource):

    def _apply_filters(self, emails, filters):
        for key in filters.items():
            f_name = key[0]
            f_val = key[1]
            if len(f_val) > 0:

                if f_name == 'recipient':
                    emails = emails.filter(Email.recipient.contains('"' + f_val + '"'))

                if f_name == 'shipment_number':
                    emails = emails.filter(Email.params["shipment_number"].contains('"' + f_val + '"'))
```

Can I use contains() to act like ilike() somehow? If not, how can I filter substring in my case? Any ideas?